# Magento 2 - How to add custom order item field on order export API

Tags: magento2, api, custom, rest-api

I added a new field on table `sales_order_item`.

I need to display it on **REST API order export**, in the "`items`" node. Is it possible to do that ?

Comment: yes it is possible, in which rest api do you need it?

Answer (score 5):

You can create a module to do it as I did below, I created a module to add the field `mpfreegifts_rule_id`.

**app/code/Vendor/FreeGifts/Plugin/OrderItemRepositoryPlugin.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\FreeGifts\Plugin;

use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemExtensionFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemExtensionInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemSearchResultInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderItemRepositoryInterface;

/**
 * Class OrderItemRepositoryPlugin
 */
class OrderItemRepositoryPlugin
{
    /**
     * Order feedback field name
     */
    const FIELD_NAME = 'mpfreegifts_rule_id';

    /**
     * Order Extension Attributes Factory
     *
     * @var OrderItemExtensionFactory
     */
    protected $extensionFactory;

    /**
     * OrderItemRepositoryPlugin constructor
     *
     * @param OrderItemExtensionFactory $extensionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(OrderItemExtensionFactory $extensionFactory)
    {
        $this->extensionFactory = $extensionFactory;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param OrderItemRepositoryInterface $subject
     * @param OrderItemInterface $orderItem
     *
     * @return OrderItemInterface
     */
    public function afterGet(OrderItemRepositoryInterface $subject, OrderItemInterface $orderItem)
    {
        $freeGifts = $orderItem->getData(self::FIELD_NAME);
        $extensionAttributes = $orderItem->getExtensionAttributes();
        $extensionAttributes = $extensionAttributes ? $extensionAttributes : $this->extensionFactory->create();
        $extensionAttributes->setMpfreegiftsRuleId($freeGifts);
        $orderItem->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);

        return $orderItem;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param OrderItemRepositoryInterface $subject
     * @param OrderItemSearchResultInterface $searchResult
     *
     * @return OrderItemSearchResultInterface
     */
    public function afterGetList(OrderItemRepositoryInterface $subject, OrderItemSearchResultInterface $searchResult)
    {
        $orderItems = $searchResult->getItems();

        foreach ($orderItems as &$item) {
            $freeGifts = $item->getData(self::FIELD_NAME);
            $extensionAttributes = $item->getExtensionAttributes();
            $extensionAttributes = $extensionAttributes ? $extensionAttributes : $this->extensionFactory->create();
            $extensionAttributes->setMpfreegiftsRuleId($freeGifts);
            $item->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
        }

        return $searchResult;
    }
}
```

**app/code/Vendor/FreeGifts/etc/di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderItemRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="vendor_freegifts_add_order_extension_attribute"
                type="Vendor\FreeGifts\Plugin\OrderItemRepositoryPlugin" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/FreeGifts/etc/extension_attributes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemInterface">
        <attribute code="mpfreegifts_rule_id" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

The result will be like that:

[image: Magento 2 add custom order item field API]

Reference: https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/adding-custom-attribute-to-api-response-in-magento-2/

Comment: Thank you. Works like a charm for quote Item attr.